# ExtJs 4: 'GET' with form.submit

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Documentation on `form.action.Submit.method` [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Submit-cfg-method)

Code:

```
    {
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'foo_name',
                buttontext: 'foo_select'
            },
        ],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Extract',
            handler: function() {
                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        form.submit({
                            url: 'excel-extraction-service',
                            method: 'GET'
                        });
                    }
            }
        }]
    }
```

Server log:

```
POST /excel-extraction-service 404
```

I'm trying to use an excel parsing/extraction service on my server. The service accepts an excel file, pareses it, and returns a json representation. The reason for GET > POST is that GET is  a *safe method* and should not change the state of the server.

Help? Thanks  in advance

**edit:** It's important to note that the form contains a `filefield`, and thus the upload is not handled via normal AJAX (documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload)). It seems that this process overrides the `method` property in the `form.submit` config.

Comment: Still can't find why this is. Sencha????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. Here's an example with the latest version. When you look in the console, you'll see it sends a get request. Post a test case.

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {

    var fp = new Ext.form.Panel({
        renderTo: document.body,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'foo'
        }]
    });

    fp.getForm().submit({
        url: 'foo',
        method: 'GET'
    });

});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12t

Comment: Well, that explains it then. You can't send a file as a GET request.

Comment: Ya sorry, I need to think through what information I include in the question. Is this not being able to send a file as a GET request just ExtJS ?

Comment: A `GET` means send the information as part of the query string. How would you send a file like that? It's not an Ext limitation.